# back button doesn't show up

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I push a ViewController on my UINavigationController, but I see no 'back' button... the NavBar is empty but there.

In my storyboard, my initial View Controller is the NavigationController, and I set the 'Top Bar' to 'None' in the Simulated Metrics section. When I switch to Inferred or Navigation Bar, everything work ok, I see the back button with text "back". (but then all my View are ugly since I removed the NavBar for a reason).

How could I preserve my design (NavBar hidden/not there) and be able to push a new ViewController with a NavBar and Back button. NavBar on demand!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: just put my AppDelegate as the UINavigationController delegate and manually hide/show the NavBar.

In my Storyboard, the navigation controller is with:

1. Simulated Metrics -> Top Bar -> None
2. Navigation Controller -> Bar Visibility -> uncheck "Shows Navigation
   Bar"

The AppDelegate .h/.m:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>


- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (something) {
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
    }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (somethingElse) {
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to configure navigation in application
try this in ApplicationDidFinishLoading Method in  App delegate

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

after use this to change view in action method of button

```
DetailViewController *ViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

  [self.navigationController pushNavigationController:ViewController animated:YES];
```